# Strange behaviour of -d conditional expression

Tags: shell, unix, scripting, ksh

My KornShell (ksh) manual says that `-d` expression returns true if the file exists and it is a directory.
So `if [[ -d file ]]` should return TRUE if `file` is a directory. But in my case this is not how it works. It returns TRUE if the file exists and is NOT a directory, but the manual of the shells says "and it is a directory". So does anyone have any idea why it is working in the opposite of what it should be?

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: What if you try `[ -d file ] && echo "yes"`?

Comment: What OS / version?  Works for me on osx 10.7.5

Comment: Note that it's true if we can determine that it exists and is a directory after following symlinks. So it returns true for a symlink to a directory and false for a directory that's in a directory you don't have access to.

Comment: Are you looking at `$?`? Update your question to show us some code that exhibits the unexpected behavior.

Comment: What do you get if you do: `d=$(mktemp -d); [[ -d "$d" ]] && echo "$d is a dir"`

Answer (score 3):

It's working fine; it's your expectations that are wrong. In shells, a **0** return value is **true**, and a **non-zero** return value is **false**.

```
$ true ; echo $?
0
$ false ; echo $?
1
```

Comment: Plausible speculation, but the OP didn't say he was examining `$?`.

Answer (score 0):

**ksh File Operator | True if:**

- -a   |   file exists
- -d   |   file is a directory
- -f   |   file is a regular file (i.e., not a directory or other special type of file)
- -r   |   You have read permission on file
- -s   |   file exists and is not empty
- -w   |   You have write permission on file
- -x   |   You have execute permission on file, or directory search permission if it is a directory
- -O   |   file You own file
- -G   |   file Your group ID is the same as that of file

**kshFileOperatorsFunction.ksh**

```
#***Function to demo ksh file Operators.***#
fileOperators(){
    echo "Entering fileOperators function."
    if [[ ! -a $1 ]]; then
        print "file $1 does not exist."
        return 1
    fi
    if [[ -d $1 ]]; then
        print -n "$1 is a directory that you may "
        if [[ ! -x $1 ]]; then
            print -n "not "
        fi
        print "search."
    elif [[ -f $1 ]]; then
         print "$1 is a regular file."
    else
         print "$1 is a special type of file."
    fi
    if [[ -O $1 ]]; then
        print 'you own the file.'
    else
        print 'you do not own the file.'
    fi
    if [[ -r $1 ]]; then
        print 'you have read permission on the file.'
    fi
    if [[ -w $1 ]]; then
        print 'you have write permission on the file.'
    fi
    if [[ -x $1 && ! -d $1 ]]; then
        print 'you have execute permission on the file.'
    fi
    echo "Exiting fileOperators function."
}
```

Reference : [O'Reilly, Learning the KornShell Volume 1](http://kauni07.files.wordpress.com/2009/03/kornshell.pdf)